# Trying to position a CSS circle over the top of an Image

Tags: html, css

I have a circle image that I want to be able to cover with a CSS circle. How do I position the CSS circle so that it always matches the same height and width as the circle image?

The image properties are as follows:

```
max-width: 270px;
height: 270px;
width: 100%;
border-radius: 50%;
border: none;
```

Thanks

```
<li class=\"mis-slide\">
    <a class=\"mis-container\" ">
        <figure>
            <img></img>
            <figcaption>
                <span></span>
                <div>Text</div>
            </figcaption>
        </figure>
    </a>
</li>
```

Comment: What about the `html`, and rest of `css`?

Comment: If possible thn provide JS Fiddle.

Comment: something like [this](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Lg99wp25/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you know the height of the circle, you can use relative position of a div below the image as

```
position: relative;
bottom: 270px;
```

or a div above the image as

```
position: relative;
top: 270px;
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/444vc9u8/3/